# Creating a function for a snap, crackle, pop

Tags: sql-server

Create a function named fncSCP that takes int n as a parameter and returns a varchar
Update the function you created in problem #1 to:
If n evenly divides into 2 then concat to your varchar the value 'Snap'
If n evenly divides into 3 then concat to your varchar the value 'Crackle'
If n evenly divides into 5 then concat to your varchar the value 'Pop'
else set your varchar the value of n. This code is not working. Im getting concat errors. Any advice?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSCP (@n INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @input INT = n;

    IF (@input % 2) <> 0
    CONCAT(varchar, 'snap')
BEGIN
    IF (@input % 3) <> 0
    CONCAT(varchar, 'crackle')
BEGIN
    IF (@input % 5) <> 0
    CONCAT(varchar, 'pop')

END; 
END;
END;
```

Comment: here is my code. Im getting a concat error

Comment: Use [Edit] and put all your code into the question.

Comment: `CONCAT(varchar,'pop')` and the rest isn't valid syntax. `CONCAT` takes multiple string expresssions and concatenates them, it doesn't accept a data type as it's first parameter. Also, you would need to use `RETURN` here. Personally I suggest having a read of the documentation on scalar functions; you'll likely learn more that way.

Answer (score 2):

To me your question reads like this (although it seems to follow on from another question?):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSCP (@n INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS

BEGIN

    RETURN
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN
                    @n % 2 <> 0
                    AND @n % 3 <> 0
                    AND @n % 5 <> 0
                THEN CAST(@n AS varchar(20))
                ELSE
                    CONCAT(
                        CASE WHEN @n % 2 = 0 THEN 'Snap' END
                        , CASE WHEN @n % 3 = 0 THEN 'Crackle' END
                        , CASE WHEN @n % 5 = 0 THEN 'Pop' END
                    )
            END
    )

END
```

Though given you've returned `varchar(10)`, that makes me think maybe this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSCP (@n INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(10) -- ought to be varchar(11); see below
AS

BEGIN

    RETURN
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN @n % 2 = 0 THEN 'Snap'
                WHEN @n % 3 = 0 THEN 'Crackle'
                WHEN @n % 5 = 0 THEN 'Pop'
                ELSE CAST(@n AS VARCHAR(10)) -- ought to be varchar(11); see below
            END
    )

END
```

Though I just read that -2147483648 is the minimum (maximum negative) value for the `int` data type, which wouldn't go into `varchar(10)`, so it would need to be `varchar(11)` in that case.

Comment: I thought I had to use an If/else statement because its a function? soemthing like this maybe

Comment: IF/ELSE doesn't really exist in SQL Server. CASE WHEN is the substitute. You can read about it [here, on W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)